# Create a constraint in a field depending of another field

Tags: python

I have a table `T1` with three field:

- `id` integer
- `Vocation` integer : `VOCATION` = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5
- `TYPE` integer : `TYPE` = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8

`TYPE` depend on `VOCATION`. For example if `VOCATION = 1`, `TYPE` should be = 2 or 3 or 4 or 6, other example if `VOCATION = 2`, `TYPE` should be = 4 or 5, etc.

I would create a constraint in `TYPE` that force the value of constraint to be, for example, 4 or 5 if the value of `VOCATION` is 2, etc.

some idea please

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
TYPE = contr( !VOCATION!)

def contr(Voc):
    if Voc == 1 :
        return [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Hi geotp, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a minute to acquaint yourself with the code formatting options. You can paste your code, highlight it and click Ctrl-K, and your code will be formatted correctly. The way it is now, it isn't valid Python. Also, your question is very unclear. What kind of table are you talking about? Python doesn't have tables as a datatype. What you're describing sounds more like a  database.

Comment: i use python in another programm as a language to calculate field

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could utilise the power of Python dictionaries and do the following:

```
>>> vocdict = {1:[2,3,4,6], 2:[4,5]}
>>> vocdict.get(1)
 [2, 3, 4, 6] 
>>> vocdict.get(2)
 [4, 5]
```